# Menu driven interface using a master page and content pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, master-pages

I seem to be having trouble trying to find an answer to this. I'm creating a website where the main page (master page) has a nice graphic in the header along with a media player that you can click and listen to songs. This main page will also contain a menu for the user to be able to navigate to various parts of the website (e.g. info, contact, media, etc). What I want is to be able to change the content section by clicking on the menus items but not refresh the master page so that the media player doesn't stop playing. I've looked into UpdatePanel and it seems to have a lot of overhead on a postback to load a page worth of content (e.g. maybe photo album, etc). Is there a fairly straight-forward way to do this using ajax or something built-in to aps.net that will allow content page updates without refreshing the master page? I'm kind of surprised I haven't found a solid solution to this using google considering that  a lot of websites are able to do this. Maybe my wording is wrong. ;) I'm using basic asp.net 4 webform template and not mvc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no better way with WebForms than to use UpdatePanels. The overhead they create is due to the way WebForms needs to keep track of each page's ViewState.

You might be able to finagle something using frames, but that seems even worse to me.

Comment: I had a feeling someone would say to use UpdatePanel :). I've heard a lot of people say that it creates a lot of postback overhead because viewstate, etc, but I think even MS uses for it their WebForms and MVC 4 template apps. :)

Comment: @u84six: No, ASP.NET MVC gets away from UpdatePanel, ViewState, etc. completely. If you want to have a nice AJAXy interface, MVC is the way to go. On the other hand, if you are stuck with WebForms, there are tricks you can use to minimize ViewState: it's just a hassle.

Comment: Maybe I'll just switch to mvc 4. I mean, this site doesn't have a lot of data driven content, so mvc doesn't really make any sense (no db required; it's a small site with mostly static info and images). I'd be stripping out 90% of the default template just to use the ajax portion of it. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do will be very ajaxy and javascript heavy using jQuery.. You will want to do something like

```
$('#someMenuElement').click(function () {
     $.ajax(...) //Fetch your data here
});

page.successFetchMethod = function (data) {
    //Render your data here
}
```

You could use something like [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) for easy template rendering of your pages. Once you have fetched the page, you can just set a flag so you know to just set the display, instead of re-fetching. You could even add in an expiration time so it will fetch a fresh copy of the data after 'x' seconds have passed.